# Не выводится информация при нажатии кнопки

Tags: c#, ajax

Только приступил к изучению AJAX. Используя IDE "MS Visual Studio 2015 Express для Web" начал разбирать пример, в котором при нажатии клавиши выводится дата, но у меня при нажатии ни чего не происходит, пожалуйста помогите в решении проблемы.
Код в файле ajax.aspx:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Ajax.aspx.cs"      Inherits="RudenSoft.jQuery.Ajax" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>          
 <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>
    <button class="b1" >send ajax</button>
    <span class="dt"></span>
 </div>
 </form>
 <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.b1').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var param = {
                count: 2, name: 'Max'
            };

            var data = JSON.stringify(param);
            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/jquery/ajax.aspx/gettime',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: data,
                success: function (data, status) {
                    var obj = data;
                    if (data.d != undefined) obj = data.d;
                    var response = eval(obj);
                    if (response.result == '1') {
                        $('.dt').html(response.s);
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert("error = " + xhr.status + thrownError);
                },
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Contetnt-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Код в файле ajax.aspx.cs:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Services;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

 namespace RudenSoft.jQuery
 {
     public partial class Ajax : System.Web.UI.Page
     {
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

         }

         [WebMethod]
         public static string gettime(int count, string name){
             var res = "";

             var d = DateTime.Now.ToString() + ", " + name;
             res = "{ \"result\":\"1\", \"s\":  \"" + d + "\"}";

             return res;
         }
     }
 }
```

Ошибка из консоли:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавьте `console.log(data);` перед `var obj = data;` и сообщите, что появилось в консоли браузера. `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', ...`

Comment: Что в инструментах разработчика показывается?

Comment: Ох уж не знаю, где Вы пример взяли, но тут явно что-то не так. Это же `WebForms`, не так ли? А там случайно на батон не нужно тоже прописать `runat="server"`? И кнопка случайно не так должна делаться: `<asp:Button...`?

Comment: В консоли вылезла следующая ошибка (ссылка): https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3KIIbzlo9PlMXh1M0FjQnlGaVU

Comment: Denis Bubnov я только начал изучение ajax и к сожалению не смогу поддержать диалог )) Мне на данный момент требуется чтобы данный пример заработал для освоения json и ajax.

Comment: Пожалуйста подскажите в какую сторону рыть?

Comment: @student007, странно, но судя по ошибке, похоже на вот это: [Устранение неполадок проверки подлинности](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/jj618331(v=ws.11).aspx) Похоже, что у Вас попросту нет доступа к вызываемому методу. Может нужно на папку с проектом дать прав пользователям: `LOCAL SERVICE`, `NETWORK SERVICE`, `IUSR`, `IIS_IUSRS`. А еще глянуть, как отображается сайт в браузере, к примеру. Открывается ли страница. Что пишет. Пока только предположения.

Comment: Не помогло, ставил разрешения пользователям указанным выше, прописывал runat="server" в батон, ошибка с подлинностью осталась. Страница также открывается в браузере показывая кнопку, но при нажатии на неё ни чего не происходит. Всё равно спасибо всем, что что-то посоветовали.

Answer (score 1):

Внесите следующие изменения в свой код:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="scm" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
        <button class="b1">send ajax</button>
        <span class="dt"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

[ScriptManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) - управляет библиотекой скриптов AJAX для ASP.NET и файлами скриптов, частичной отрисовкой страниц и созданием прокси-класса клиента для веб-служб и служб приложений.

А еще немного изменил бы `javascript`, вот так:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.b1').click(function (e) {
            // тут Ваш код ajax
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

И небольшой вопрос, зачем делать отмену действия браузера: `e.preventDefault();`? Ну, это было отступление, теперь снова далее, что бы переделал еще. Кнопку внутри формы сделал бы вот такой:

```
<button ID="btnGetTime">send ajax</button>
```

Если у Вас в класс `"b1"` не содержит никаких стилей можем спокойно убрать. Ну и  `javascript` поменялся бы под кнопку и стал бы вот таким:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $('#btnGetTime').click(function() {
            // e.preventDefault(); - делать не нужно
            $.ajax({
                // тут Ваш код ajax
            });
            return false;
        });
     }); 
</script>
```

И еще один небольшой совет, мне очень уж не нравится Ваш `url`, сделайте вот так:

```
url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/ajax.aspx/gettime") %>'
```

По поводу использования некоторых аттрибутов в Вашем `ajax` я не совсем уверен, к примеру не думаю, что Вам нужен `beforeSend`, и содержимое `error` тоже можно упростить.

---

`ScriptManager` - использовать не обязательно, но на всякий случай я его упомянул. У Вас `url` такой интересный: `/jquery/ajax.aspx/gettime`. Есть небольшой совет: создать проект с нуля, при этом не называть классы и папки ключевыми словами типа: *jquery*, *ajax* и т.п.  Про `preventDefault` можете почитать тут: [Действия браузера по умолчанию](https://learn.javascript.ru/default-browser-action)

Comment: Денис спасибо Вам, извините, что долго не отвечал, были проблемы со здоровьем. Исправил свой код согласно Вашим рекомендациям:

Comment: <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div>
          <asp:ScriptManager ID="scm" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
          <button id="btnGetTime" >send ajax</button>
          <span class="dt"></span>
         </div>
         </form>

Comment: В элементе button заместо класса  class="b1" вставил идентификатор btnGetTime. И функцию переделал по инструкции выше. В итоге ошибка изменилась на: "https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3KIIbzlo9PlRnY5Z05fS1lHR0E". Так понимаю не может найти функцию gettime. На данный момент ковыряюсь с данной ошибкой плюс изучаю материал который Вы дали.  @Denis Bubnovещё раз спасибо.

Comment: @student007, не могу посмотреть ошибку, которую Вы в ссылке дали. Вы в формировании ajax-запроса для url использовали `ResolveUrl`?

Comment: @student007, добавьте новую ошибку в вопрос что ли, чтобы было понятно в чем проблема, чтобы можно было помочь Вам :) И для url используйте `ResolveUrl` )

Comment: извините за битую ссылку, по этой должно получиться https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3KIIbzlo9PlRnY5Z05fS1lHR0E   Сообщение "POST http://localhost:55683/ajax.aspx/gettime 404 (Not Found)". Урл такой: url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/ajax.aspx/gettime") %>', на данный момент разбираюсь или название функции у меня указано не верно, или ещё что-то.

Comment: @student007, проверьте политики безопасности сервера, где находится метод, возможно он блокирует запрос. Либо попробуйте поэксперементировать с url, так: `'<%= ResolveUrl("/ajax.aspx/gettime") %>'` или так:  `'<%= ResolveUrl("/jQuery/Ajax.aspx/gettime") %>'`, по разному попробуйте.

Comment: И еще, попробуйте данные так написать: `data: "{ 'count': '2', 'name': 'Max'}"`, кажется Вы там кавычки у двойки забыли, может ему это не нравится... У имени параметра можно кавычки не ставить, а у значения - обязательно нужно вроде бы.

Answer (score 0):

Иногда из за настройки сервера ajax url работает case sensitive, измените код

```
url: '/jQuery/Ajax.aspx/gettime'
```

или вот так

```
url: 'Ajax.aspx/gettime'
```

Comment: К сожалению не сработало.